# Is using SERIAL fine for the primary key when creating a table of all the comments made by users?

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, ddl, create-table

I am trying to learn postgres after working with mongodb for a while, and I'm wondering how to have a unique ID for each `comment`.

I have a foreign key `userId` for which user created the comment, but for primary key I need some kind of `commentId`.  Is it fine to use `SERIAL` for my `commentId`?   Or, is there a better approach like UUIDs?  I don't know if I will ever have to migrate the data.

Comment: both `uuid` and `SERIAL` are usable in postgres. SERIAL creates a sequence and assigns to a column when creating a table

Comment: thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the actual value of the comment id does not interest you (just the fact that it's there and it's unique), `serial` is a good choice for such a column. Note that in modern PostgreSQL databases (since 7.3), creating a `serial` does not automatically mean it will have a unique constraint, so you'd have to handle that explicitly. E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT REFERENCES users(id), -- You should probably also index it
    comment VARCHAR(200) -- Or any other reasonable size
)
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comments, a similar behavior could be created for a `UUID` column by giving it a default value of a newly generated `UUID`.

First, you'd have to install the postgres-contrib` package (if you don't have it installed yet). E.g., On Red Hat based linuxes, you could run (as root):

```sh
$ dnf install postgresql-contrib
```

Then, from a privileged user, you need to create the extension:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

This will create a `generate_uuid_v1` function you could use:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id UUID DEFAULT UUID_GENERATE_V1() PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id INT REFERENCES users(id), -- You should probably also index it
    comment VARCHAR(200) -- Or any other reasonable size
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a built in way to make a uuid similarly?

Comment: @user1354934 it's a bit clunkier, but sure, it's definitely doable. See my edited answer for details.

Comment: wow thanks a lot Mureinik!  I realize uuid is probably slower, but I think it would help when migrating in the future if needed, right?  Thanks

Comment: @user1354934 Not sure what exactly you mean by "easier", but using UUID should ensure each comment has a unique ID no matter where you need to migrate the data to, even if you merge it with some other comment source.

Comment: Thank you sorry that is what i meant!  I am really new to this.  Appreciate your help!